# I changed my description on YouTube but it still shows the old description

Tags: youtube

I changed my YouTube channel's description but when you search up my channel name it still shows the old description. I know it takes time to change for everyone to see the new one but it has been almost 5 years.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's showing the description from five years ago or you changed the description to the new one five years ago?

Comment: It is showing the description from 5 years ago.

Comment: I tried this today. At first it didn't work, but then it did. So I am not sure. There are two different places to edit the description, including one where empty lines can not be inserted. Perhaps the place where you ***can*** actually add empty lines is the place to save from and then it will update?

Comment: Generally, YouTube will change your description immediately. But a few times I have noticed that YouTube will take some time to reflect your updated description.

Answer (score -1):

Use Facebook Sharing debugger. Punch in your link and click "Scrape again". Copy and post the new link with debugged metadata. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: The question seems about YouTube...